# I have lost data but it's not deleted or overwritten

Tags: data-recovery, partitioning, data-loss

I am a beginner, so I know nothing. I installed lubuntu 12.04 so that I can learn, but I mistakenly installed it on a partition that contains 90 gigabytes of data.  However, my data wasn't deleted: I knew that when I wanted to install Windows that my data is still there, by knowing the used space of the HDD.

Now the problem is: I can't find my data on Linux in the same partition, neither can I find the whole partition in Windows. I think it's hidden, so how can I show it?
If it isn't hidden how can I find it?? The data was in the form of multiple files and various kinds (video,docs,music..etc).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very ambiguous, how do you know it isn't deleted if you can't find it?

If you are trying to work out where your hard drive space has been taken up you can use a tool called [baobab](http://www.marzocca.net/linux/baobab/index.html). It can be installed using `sudo apt-get install baobab` (if it is not already installed).

There is also a chance if you think you installed it on a partition with data, that it may have been completely wiped if you cannot find the data anywhere.